# TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1e-04>)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a simple ratio metric for 10000 images from the mnist dataset in a simple DNN architecture in keras and I unfortunately faced this error<`TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1e-04>)`> at line 51 while trying to save the model.I looked everywhere but none of the answers were helpful.Here's my code

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist 
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 
X_train, X_test = X_train[:10000], X_test[:1000]
y_train, y_test = y_train[:10000], y_test[:1000]
X_train, X_test = X_train.reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0, X_test.reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0
y_train, y_test = to_categorical(y_train, 10), to_categorical(y_test, 10)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

#Implement a simple ratio metric(y_true over y_pred)
class Ratio(Metric):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
         super().__init__(**kwargs)
         #add_weight() method creates the variables needed to keep track of
         self.mean_ratio = self.add_weight("mean_ratio", initializer="zeros")

    #Updater
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.add(y_true, tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32))
        y_pred = tf.add(y_pred, tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32))
        ratio = tf.divide(y_true, y_pred)
        ratio = tf.reduce_mean(ratio)
        self.mean_ratio.assign(ratio)

    def result(self):
        return self.mean_ratio
    
    #Reset the variables
    def reset_state(self):
        self.mean_ratio.assign(0)

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config}

dnn = Sequential()
dnn.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(784, ), activation="relu"))
dnn.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
dnn.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
dnn.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
dnn.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=[Ratio()])
dnn.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
dnn.save("custom_component_model.h5") #Error line
dnn = load_model("custom_component_model.h5", custom_objects={"Ratio":Ratio})
dnn.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: If I read the error message correctly, what you have is a single number. It should be trivial to cast into JSON as such, but it's probably not a useful or correct tensor. Perhaps the library you are using has a bug in a corner case, or perhaps they don't think they need to support structures which are not useful.

Comment: I ran you code and it ran flawlessly and with that I believe this is a version issue. My TensorFlow version - `2.5.0` . Also, just saying that your `ratio` metric is going above `1` so there might be a bug in it. I didn't check its behavior so it might be ideal but still just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that I had a variable named as `eps` meant to help avoid zero division in my previous code with some changes and found out that the given value in the error `1e-04` is the same as the value of eps and because the variable was saved in the google colab's cache, the code faced errors.I ran the code in another notebook and as the others mentioned in the comments, the code worked just fine.